# To Add open in browser plugin in cordova (Xcode)

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have created an application on both the ios and android platforms using cordova in xcode. When I click a link it automatically goes within the app itself. So I need an idea to solve this problem by opening a link in a browser. Is there any code or plugin in cordova to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inAppBrowser plugin.

[Read the documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html)

You can install the plugin to you project by,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Add this to your **config.xml**,

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

You have to change anchor tags in your app to look like this,

```
<a href="#" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com', '_system', 'location=yes');">
```

Now build for Android and iOS again using,

```
cordova build ios

cordova build android
```

Now it should work.

**Note** : Due to a bug in Cordova Android 7.1.3 InAppBrowser doesn't work in that version. Make sure to use a version newer or older.